# Spring beans not autowired into Custom Java Validator class during unit tests

Tags: spring, validation, unit-testing, bean-validation, spock

I have a model class annotated with Java validation framework annotations.

```
@ValidClient
public class Client implements Serializable{
    private static final long SERIAL_VERSION_UID = 1L;
    @NotNull
    private Integer primaryKey;
    @NotEmpty
    private String id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    ...
}
```

I have written a custom validator class 'ClientValidator' to validate the below model class as per the business requirements.

```
public class ClientIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidClient, String> {
    @Autowired
    private IClientService service;

    private Map<String, Client> clientMap = null;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidClient constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String clientId, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if(clientMap == null) {
            Map<String, Client> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

            for (Client client : service.getAllClients()) {
                map.put(client.getId(), client);
            }
            clientMap = map;
        }

        return clientMap.get(clientId) !=null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, my custom validator is autowired with a Spring bean which works fine in production code. However, when I try to write unit test for the model object `Client`, then the  Spring autowired field `IClientService service` is null and is not autowired. Since I don't have access to the instance of the custom validator instantiated, I'm not sure how to populate this autowired field. I wonder how it is autowired in production code, but not in unit test code.

Below is the Spock unit test code I wrote.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestAppConfig.class])
class ClientTest extends Specification {
    def "test"(){
        expect:
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = TestAppConfig.getApplicationContext().getBean("validator")
        def validator1 = validator.getValidator()
        validator1.validate(input)

        where:
        input | messageTemplates
        new Client() | "test"
    }
}
```

How do I autowire an instance of `IClientService` into the custom validator while unit test?

Comment: How about using `@Autowired ClientIdValidator clientIdValidator` inside `ClientTest`? Does that work for you?

Comment: Just an ignorant comment, as I haven't used spock, but don't you need to also use the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation to use the spring runner on `ClientTest`?

Comment: @geoand ClientIdValidator is not a spring bean defined in the Spring configuration file. It is instantiated automatically by Java validation framework. While running it as non-unit test code, somehow the spring bean `IClientService` is automatically injected into the validator. I'm not sure how.

Comment: @Augusto In Spock, the same is achieved via `@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestAppConfig.class])`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing the @ValidClient from the POJO. It is not required here since I'm annotated my method parameters with this annotation.

By removing the custom annotation, now the default validator is being invoked.